# Protect swf Object using Javascript

Tags: security, flash, decompiler

I'm developing a web application that load a swf object;
I'm asking how can I protect this SWF object from Decompiler ? How can I secure it!
Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is apparently 3rd party software that can "lock" your swf files. I've never used them.. just did a Google search.

Comment: [ActionScript code protection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActionScript_code_protection)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

Your SWF is about as secure as it will get when it is exported from Adobe Flash.